# Embed script not loading HTML at the right position

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hubspot

We're embedding a 3rd party form (HubSpot Form) on our site and sometimes the HTML of the form isn't in the right place. It should be right after the script.

```
<script>hbspt.forms.create({ 
css: '',
portalId: '1552633',
formId: '6c551c1f-f5a6-453d-93d3-4169c8f563c0'});
</script>
```

and the HTML of the form should be after the script

```
<div class="hbspt-form" id="hbspt-form-1479681169480">
```

But sometimes, the HTML of the form appears below the footer of the page. The script is in the right place. Just the html that it generated is not.

Any ideas what may cause this?

[image]

Comment: show all of your page code, html and css,

Comment: what are the styles being applied on hbspt-form there may be something in that that's causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a more specific solution to this issue.

For any HubSpot users, what I did to solve the problem was added a class to the div where I wrapped the code in and then in the embed code, I added

```
target: '.class'
```

This makes sure that the form loads within that class instead of somewhere else
 and that solved the issue.

Comment: I faced same issue, and adding `target: '.class'` fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had same kind of issue. Finally I got the solution by adding target class and Instance Id.

For ex:

```
<div class="hubspot-form">
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2-legacy.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/v2.js"></script>
<script>
    hbspt.forms.create({
        css: '',
        portalId: '1552633',
        formId: '6c551c1f-f5a6-453d-93d3-4169c8f563c0',
        taget: '.hubspot-form',
        formInstanceId: '1'
    });
</script>
```

More details please look at this https://knowledge.hubspot.com/articles/kcs_article/forms/why-has-my-embedded-form-moved-on-my-page

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing in a container like this:

```
<div class='external-form-loader' style='margin-left: auto: margin-right: auto; width:500px'>
    <script>
        hbspt.forms.create({
        css: '',
        portalId: '1552633',
        formId: '6c551c1f-f5a6-453d-93d3-4169c8f563c0'
    });
    </script>
    <div class="hbspt-form" id="hbspt-form-1479681169480"></div>
</div>
```

Style the div as you like.

If the issue still persists, you can easily handle it with css.
Cheers..

Answer (score 0):

I anyone is using Blazor Web Assembly, here is what I did to get this to work.

In Razor page.

```
@code {

    [Inject]
    public IJSRuntime JSRuntime { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("ShowForm", null);
    }
    
}

<div class="hubspot-form">

//Form will display here.

</div>
```

In Index.html.

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js"></script>

    <script>

        function ShowForm() {

            hbspt.forms.create({
                region: "na1",
                portalId: "SOMEID",
                formId: "SOMEID",
                target: ".hubspot-form"
            });
        }
    </script>
```